# jquery check if inArray from php array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have an array in php I pull into my jquery like so:

```
var hide = <?php echo json_encode($user_dashboard); ?>;
```

this give me:

```
var hide = "a:2:{i:0;s:18:\"dashboard-progress\";i:1;s:19:\"dashboard-bookmarks\";}";
```

I had some code that working fine when the array was just a string but now it doesnt compare the elements:

```
if (  $.inArray( $this.attr('id') , hide) !=  -1 )
```

basically its just testing to group of elements ID's against the array. If the array contains the ID then doing something. When the array was just:

```
var hide = "dashboard-progress", "dashboard-bookmarks";
```

It worked fine. But now I have to store the array in php and MySQL.

`var_dump($user_dashboard)` contains `string(67) "a:2:{i:0;s:18:"dashboard-progress";i:1;s:19:"dashboard-bookmarks";}"`

The data is pulled from an array being put into MySQL field using php serialize.

Comment: What you have is a string, not an array. It's also very badly formatted; it looks like an attempt at JSON but it has lots of syntax errors. You need to fix your data before you can get this working

Comment: That is not valid json!! So how did you really generate it

Comment: Looks more like the result of a PHP `serialize()`

Comment: Show us what is in `$user_dashboard` before you `json_encode()` it

Comment: @RiggsFolly I updated my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea the string you have in `$user_dashboard` is a serialized array, so try this code instead, to first convert that string into an array and then convert it to a JSON String

```
var hide = <?php echo json_encode(unserialize($user_dashboard)); ?>;
```

Comment: Ya, I just realized I forgot to get it back to an array from the string when I updated that code.